# problem with Ext JS grid

Tags: extjs, xt

iam new to Ext js
iam displaying a tree inside a grid. it works fine.but according to my new requirement, i have to use seperate coloumn headers for parent node and child nodes.is it possible to have more than one coloumn header for a single grid?

Answer (score 1):

**ExtJs** does not support multiple column headers out of the box.  It would most likely be some type of plug-in but a quick google search didn't turn anything up.

There are two plug-ins you might find useful, the second one may be a sort of compromise.

**ExtJs TreeGrid**

- [TreeGrid Information/Download](http://www.max-bazhenov.com/dev/ux.maximgb.treegrid/index.php)
- [TreeGrid Example](http://www.max-bazhenov.com/dev/ux.maximgb.treegrid/examples/client_expander/index.html)

**ExtJs Multiple Level of Grouping in Grids**

- [Multi Level Grouping Information/Download](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?42454-Multiple-level-of-grouping-in-grids)
- [Multi Level Example](http://jaffa.sourceforge.net/JaffaRIATests/tests/extjs/multigroup/MultiGroup.html)